# How to check if screen requires to scroll down to see search result if there is a list of results available in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, events

Entered a keyword into a search bar and it is showing a list of related results available, so  i want to scroll down if required. Please help me. Below is the code snippet

```
for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){ 
    
    //Import data for company names.
    cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
    cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    //Here i'm reading and writing inputs from excel sheet
    WebElement
    SearchBar = driver.findElement(By.className("search-global-typeahead__input"));
    SearchBar.sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue(), Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    SearchBar.submit();

    //Thread.sleep(3000);
    //wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    //SearchBar.clear();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

}
```

Comment: anyone help me.

Comment: Have you tried out javascript scrollIntoView option: `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);`